# MYSQL copy from other table only if row does not exist

Tags: mysql

I have an existing MYSQL products table that has (amongst others) productID (autoinc) quantity productCode description

I have now been supplied with a spreadsheet that has all the products above + more new products.

I need to import only the new products that don't exist in the products table.

I am using sequel Pro on a mac. When I select the advanced section and select 'skip existing rows' it populates with `productID` = `productID`.

So I don't see a method to say if productCode = productCode skip this row.

I have created an new table productsAll that has all the new data in it and matched fields.

How do I loop through the productsAll table but only insert into the products table if the productCode does not exist.

Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You can use INSERT IGNORE

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO TABLE1 (SELECT * FROM TABLE2)
```

Comment: Hi @semyon Tikhonenko . Will this work on just the productCode field (this is not an index). Ie I need it to ignore when Table1.productCode = Table2. productCode

Comment: This will not work if productCode is not an index. You can make your productCode a primary key or unique index, perform this operation and delete a key.